# Why doesn't it work when I try to compare doubles in java?

Tags: java, comparison, double

I get that this is a dumb question but I couldn't figure this out on google so this is my last resort.

Why is it that when I try to compare two doubles that are variables that I know are equal, it returns false? Here's an example that I hope is more clear:

```
double x = 323.23
double y = 323.23
System.out.println(x==y)
```

Output:

```
false
```

Why does this happen? Also, why does it print true if you just compare two doubles that are not variables or a double that is a variable and a double that is not? example:

```
double x = 323.23
System.out.println(x==323.23)
System.out.println(323.23==323.23)
```

output:

```
true
true
```

Comment: you sure it return false, cause it return true on mine

Comment: The first part print `true` for me.

Comment: Please print your real, compilable, code.

Comment: It returns true when I print it out; could you share the whole document of code that you have to see if there is a problem somewhere else?

Comment: don't compare floats with `==`: http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/Comparing%20floating%20point%20numbers.htm

Comment: -1 [Your premise is wrong.](https://ideone.com/wuXlAc)

Comment: Seriously dude, you should check your facts before posting Questions like this.  Your code will not output "false" on any conformant implementation of Java.  Now, you may be seeing strange results with floating point and `==` in other code ... but if you are going to post bogus examples like this instead of the real code, we can't help you.

Comment: Contrary to the notice, I did not mark this as a duplicate. I voted to close for being unclear.

Answer (score -7):

You should not compare doubles on an objet level. Your sample prints `true` because the compile just optimizes your code so that x and y point to the same object. Instead use `Double.equals()`. If you think about how doubles can be represented even equal values can have different bit configurations. If checking lesser/greater use the `Double.compareTo()` method.

Comment: What does `Double` and objects have to do with this question?

Comment: In addition, `Double.compareTo()` has different semantics than `==`, `<=`, etc, so it can't be used exactly as a drop-in replacement.